# can I use Azure MXCHIP IoT DevKit with google cloud

Tags: azure

https://www.seeedstudio.com/AZ3166-IOT-Developer-Kit.html

I am planning to setup a project that can work with both google cloud IoT and Azure IoT. Is it possble to reuse Azure IoT kit for that ?